# Extended ASCII character in MATLAB plot label/title

Tags: matlab, character-encoding, plot, extended-ascii

I need to put word "naïve" on a plot, and save it as PNG and PDF. Sometime it's in a title, or in tick label. Whatever I've tried I always get right arrow symbol (png) or empty space (pdf) instead of the `ï` character.

I've looked into functions native2unicode and unicode2native, but they seems to be only for file input/output.

I cannot believe this task is so difficult in MATLAB.

I'm using MATLAB 2012b undier Windows 7.

---

The symbol `ï` has ascii code `0239`, or hex `0xEF`. MATLAB shows it in console if it's entered with `Alt-0239`, but displays as empty square.

[image: disp(ï) example]

MATLAB returns 26 as character's code:

```
>> int32('Naïve')
ans =
          78          97          26         118         101
```

This symbol isn't present in MATLAB's [TeX Character Sequence Table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text_props.html#String).

Comment: Which OS / Matlab combination do you have? Using `ï` in plot titles and calling `disp('ï')` works just fine for me in R2013a on OSX 10.8.3. Is the font you are using able display the character properly in other applications?

Comment: I think the OP's problem is that the displayed character isn't preserved when the plot is converted to .png or .pdf - not that he can't show it in a plot. In other words - it is in the conversion (I imagine using a `saveas(gcf, 'mydir/myFile.png')` type of stat ement) that things go wrong. @yuk - can you give a complete code sample to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @Floris: No, I actually cannot show this character on the figure in MATLAB itself. Saving it to either png or pdf does not make a difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This must work:

```
X=rand(10,1)
Y=rand(10,1)
plot(X,Y)
title('na\"{i}ve','interpreter','latex');
```

If you need you can also change font and size , etc.

By the way, take a look at

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Special_Characters

Comment: Yes, it works! Thanks a lot. Especially for the cool reference.